Can you look at a home weather station's forecasts during Shabbat?
There's a type of home electronic gadget called a weather station.  Weather stations can display the temperature and other things.  There's usually a base station, plus a wireless outdoor sensor.  An example weather station is the La Crosse 308-1417.  Here's a photo from Amazon:

Many weather stations can generate weather forecasts locally.  Others can use Wi-Fi to fetch and display forecasts from AccuWeather or another service.
During Shabbos, if you leave a high-end weather station plugged in:  It will generate or fetch weather forecasts automatically, and it will display them on-screen.  Is it okay to let it do these things, and to look at the screen to view the forecasts?
You don't have to push any buttons or tap the screen.  It's all automatic.
If you cite sources, please preferably cite Modern Orthodox ones.  Thanks!

Related: Can one use a weather-dependent lawn sprinkler on Shabbat?

What would be the problem?

This post suggests that, if you leave your PC on for Shabbos, it may be obligatory to shut off the screen.  ❧ This thread suggests that using an electrical timer may be problematic on Shabbos. Perhaps weather stations use an electronic timer chip to trigger periodic forecast updates. ❧ Many people shut off their phones, laptops, TVs, and radios before Shabbos. When confronted with a new type of gadget which I've never left on during Shabbos before, it makes me wonder what one should do.

You get yourself into a realm that has nothing to do with Halachah but Hashkafah. Some may say - there's an infinite number of levels of Shabbos precautions - maybe you shouldn't look at your microwave, phone, car, electric blinds, digital watch, etc in fear that it would lead to some transgression. It's a pity we don't have the same level of precautions for interpersonal Mitzvos :(

@shmosel שטרי הדיוטות
